# The beautiful way for setting m and p responsively for a `Box` in Material-UI v4

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

For a `Box` component in material-ui v4, margin and padding can be set with an array or object using different values for different breakpoints for responsive design. Is there a convenient way using something like `smUp` or `mpDown` setting values for e.g. all windows sizes larger than `md`?

I really like the new features for responsive design in the new material-ui library, but the documentation seems to need a little bit more improvements :)

I can do this without any problem by setting an array with all five elements like `<Box m={[1, 1, 2, 2, 3]}>`, but I find it could be much better if there is a way like this: `<Box m={{smDown:1, mdUp:2, xl:3}}>`.

Sorry I'm not sure if this question is silly and not qualified as an issue in material-ui github repo. It would be wonderful if any of you can give me some tips or encouragements to put it on their official github :P Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of the breakpoints behave as "up" except for "xs" which acts as a default (i.e. mobile-first styling approach).

In the example in the [documentation](https://material-ui.com/system/basics/#object), it shows the CSS produced for `<Box p={{ xs: 2, sm: 3, md: 4 }} />` to be the following:

```
padding: 16px; /* xs */
@media (min-width: 600px) { /* sm */
  padding: 24px;
}
@media (min-width: 960px) { /* md */
  padding: 32px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I've just read the doc and tested in sandbox. So that means I cannot have a "down".. That is quite fine always to have an "xs" as default value. Thank you.